# vb.net Implementing an existing View as a Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a vb.net application, and have a view 'editcompany.aspx'.

I am in the process of consolidating a number of pages/views in the application into one page, where each view is displayed on a different tab within the page.

I created a new `GeneralDetailsModule.ascx` file in App/Controls, and copied the markup & code across from the `editcompany.aspx` & `editcompany.aspx.vb` files into the `GeneralDetailsModule.ascx` & `GeneralDetailsModule.ascx.vb` files respectively.

There were a couple of things I had to change slightly in the code when doing this in order to ensure that I didn't get any compilation errors, but this appears to now be fine. However, when I try to build my application, I now get an error stating:

> 'BC30203 Identifier expected.

and this is occurring in the file `editcompany.aspx.designer.vb

After copying the code across from `editcompany.aspx.vb` to `GeneralDetailsModule.ascx.vb`, I then commented all of the code in `editcompany.aspx.vb`, in order that it wouldn't conflict, and removed the markup from `editcompany.aspx`- and used an instance of the newly created module instead, i.e. where I previously had:

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="addClient" CssClass="ajax__tab_CJX" runat="server">
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="tp_general" runat="server" Enabled="true" HeaderText="General">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="body">
                <!--- Full HTML markup for the content of the panel here -->
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
    <!-- HTML markup for other tabs here -->
</cc1:TabContainer>
```

I now have:

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="addClient" CssClass="ajax__tab_CJX" runat="server">
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="tp_general" runat="server" Enabled="true" HeaderText="General">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="body">
                <uc1:GDM ID="GD_1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
    <!-- HTML markup for other tabs here -->
</cc1:TabContainer>
```

`GDM` is defined at the top of `editcompany.aspx` with:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/GeneralDetailsModule.ascx" TagName="GDM" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

The above error that I'm getting when trying to build my application states that it is occurring in `editcompany.aspx.designer.vb` on line 14, which is the line:

```
<link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

inside the `<head></head>` tags, and this line hasn't been changed at all- nor has the file it's pointing to.

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error?
Nothing I've found on Google or SO so far seem to explain how I can fix it...

Comment: Should the `.vb` file have HTML in it like that? I thought it would have things like `Protected WithEvents myTextBox As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`.

Comment: Apologies, I've worded that in a slightly confusing way. The `.vb` file doesn't have any HTML in it- the error displayed in Visual Studio states that it's occurring in the designer.vb file (on line 14)- the designer is the graphical part of the file. If I look at the source for that file (editcompany.aspx), then line 14 is that `<link href=.... />` line.

Comment: I haven't touched the `designer.vb` file myself- as I understand, that is automatically generated by Visual Studio, based on the code written in the .aspx.vb file, and the HTML in the .aspx file...?

Comment: What is line 14 in editcompany.aspx.designer.vb? If you can't persuade VS to show it to you, you could open it in a text editor.